# docker buildx not copying files when in production

Tags: docker, buildx

I am having an issue where the docker buildx tool doesn't properly copy files to the production container. For example:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:16.14.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN apk update && apk add python3 g++ make && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN yarn install
COPY . ./
RUN yarn run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# Default port exposure
EXPOSE 80

# Copy .env file and shell script to container
COPY ./env.sh /usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

All of the files from build will copy properly. However, the nginx.conf and env.sh will report as not found. Any ideas?

P.S: This seems to be an issue with nginx:alpine. No clue

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting, and what command produces it?  I wouldn't normally expect a file named `env.sh` to be executable; do you need to use the `.` special shell command to run it in the container shell context, or to inject the configuration settings using something like the `docker run --env-file` option?